# Can We Add a Dimension To The TISE To Get All Steady States In Time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

Suppose I have the Time Independent Schrodinger Equation (TISE) in 1D, if I add a second dimension, does the state in 2D now represent all the 1D states in time?

Similarly, if I have the TISE in 3D will a 4D TISE represent all 3D solution's in time.

I suppose this would require

$$
\Psi(x, y) = \Psi(x, t) = \psi(x)\phi(t) = \frac{-\hbar}{2m}\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2}{dy^2}\right)\psi(x, y) + (V(x, y) - E)\psi(x, y) = \left(\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2} + (V(x) - E)\psi(x)\right)e^{\frac{iEt}{\hbar}}
 $$
Or...
$$
\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2}{dy^2}\right)\psi(x, y) + (V(x, y) - E)\psi(x, y) = \left(\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2} + (V(x, \textbf{t}) - E)\psi(x)\right)e^{\frac{iEt}{\hbar}}
$$
For a time varying potential.

To summarize the question: can we "stick on" another dimension of space to get steady states in time?

Thanks!

Comment: No, the TISE is only valid for an unchanging potential.

Comment: @Johnny Thank you for the comment! To clarify: 
0: What if the potential does not change
1: Can the TDSE be used with a time varying potential?

Comment: it’s called time *independent* SE.  For time-dependent problems, *v.g.* time-dependent potentials, the solution techniques are different.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you, I am just not sure how to go about it or what equation to use for a time-varying potential (which is why I have asked here if time can just be another dimension). Would you be willing to point me in the direction of those techniques?

Comment: see https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/13%3A_Molecular_Spectroscopy/13.11%3A_Time-Dependent_Perturbation_Theory or http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_dep.pdf .  These problems are much harder to solve.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you!